# tmux: can a program running in a pane resize the pane?

Tags: tmux

Context: I have a window split into three panes.  The top pane is running a script which shows my mercurial status by occasionally running 'hg xl'.  My script knows how many lines are output by the command.

Is there a way I can have this program resize its pane to be exactly the right number of lines for this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your script run a tmux command to resize the pane to a chosen y height, eg 30 lines:

```
tmux resize-pane -t "$TMUX_PANE" -y 30
```

The environment variable `TMUX_PANE` will have been set by tmux in the shell running in the pane, or you may already know it (e.g. 0.0 for the first pane).